# Installing MuJoCo

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to Install MuJoCo but I cannot create the required directory ~/.mujoco. I obtain the following error:

```
You appear to be missing MuJoCo.  We expected to find the file here: /Users/NAME/.mujoco/mjpro150
```

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this error, it's expected that you manually create that folder, and follow the instructions found at: https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py#install-mujoco

You'll also need to visit the website referenced in the instructions and obtain a license file which will be placed in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after switching to MacOS Catalina. I had **mujoco200** which was working fine in Mojave. Then I just downloaded **mjpro150** and added it to the same **~/.mujoco** folder.

I have also gone through some hacky applications listed  [here](https://github.com/openai/mujoco-py/issues/463#issuecomment-554377712).